# weird tableView animation when using insert function

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation, uiscrollview

I'm trying to insert number more cells in the table view when the user reaches the bottom of the table. the insert is working fine, but a weird animation is happening when scrolling up.

I tried to add `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` before and after the `insert()` method. but this didn't help. I tried to add `tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never` in `viewDidLoad` and it didn't help.

the code I tried is:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if tableView.contentOffset.y >= (tableView.contentSize.height - tableView.frame.size.height) {
            loadMoreCells()
        }

func loadMoreCells() {
       ServerRequests.getDataServerRequest(id: provider.ID, page: page) { (foundEpisodes) in
            if foundEpisodes.count > 0 {
                let previous = self.episodes.count
                self.episodes.insert(contentsOf: foundEpisodes, at: self.episodes.count)
                self.isViewOpen.insert(contentsOf: [Bool](repeatElement(false, count: foundEpisodes.count)), at: self.isViewOpen.count)
                var indexPathsToBeInserted = [IndexPath]()
                for i in previous..<self.episodes.count{
                    indexPathsToBeInserted.append(IndexPath(row: i, section: 0))
                }
                self.tableView.insertRows(at: indexPathsToBeInserted, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
            }
        }
    }
```

Am I calling the insert in the wrong place? or what is the wrong thing I am doing ?

**UPDATE**

in `viewDidLoad`:

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: NIB_NAME, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: NIB_IDENTIFIRE)
```

in `cellForRow`:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: NIB_IDENTIFIRE, for: indexPath) as! EpisodePerProviderTableViewCell
    cell.setUpCell(tableView: tableView, episode: episodes[indexPath.row], indexPath: indexPath, isViewOpen: isViewOpen)

    return cell
```

the `setUpCell` function is:

```
unc setUpCell(tableView: UITableView, episode: Episode, indexPath: IndexPath, isViewOpen: [Bool]) {
    isMenuVisible = false
    menuView.isHidden = true
    if (isViewOpen[indexPath.row]){
        descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 100
        moreLessLabel.text = "Less"
    }else{
        descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 2
        moreLessLabel.text = "More"
    }
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()

    self.isViewOpen = isViewOpen
    self.indexPath = indexPath
    self.tableView = tableView
    self.episode = episode
    arrowButton.transform = .identity

    //set up cell content
    if let myDate = dateFormatter.date(from: episode.episodePostDate) {
        postedDate.text = dateFormatter.timeSince(from: myDate as NSDate)
    }
    episodeImage.windless.start()
    episodeImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: episode.episodeImageUrl ?? ""), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "FalloundPlayerLogo")) { (providerImage, error, SDImageCacheType, url) in
        self.episodeImage.windless.end()
    }
    title.text = episode.episodeName
    durationLabel.text = "".formatted(time: Float(episode.episodeDuration), withoutSec: true)
    descriptionLabel.text = episode.episodeDescription
}
```

Comment: Can you explain when do you want loadMoreCells() to be called?

Comment: @VadimF. when the user reaches the bottom of the table, or in other words when the last cell is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is because loadMoreCells is called too many times.

try using this check instead of willDisplay:

```
if indexPath.row == yourArrayOfCells.count - 1{
    loadMoreCells()
}
```

**UPDATE**

So I have some how of the same issue, after some digging I found this solution for myself :

```
//conform to UIScrollViewDelegate

let threshold : CGFloat = 10.0 // threshold from bottom of tableView
var isLoadingMore = false //checks if API session ended

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height;

    if !isLoadingMore && (maximumOffset - contentOffset) <= threshold {

        self.isLoadingMore = true
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            loadMoreCells() 
            self.isLoadingMore = false
        }
    }
}
```

If the API request happening too fast and the load looks funny you can add a delay :

```
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            loadMoreCells() 
            self.isLoadingMore = false
        }
```

If it won't work I will assume that the issue is not in the code you provided.

**UPDATE-2**

Those 2 funcs in setUpCell() aren't neccessery :

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: still did not solve the problem. The rest of the code is very simple. But if you would like to see more, i'll add it here

Comment: @mahdi Please do, If you have a link to Github it would be even better

Comment: @mahdi just to make sure, you did try to change the willDisplay func to scrollViewDidScroll ?

Comment: @mahdi from what I see you are downloading an image when you setting each cell?

Comment: yes, but I tried to comment out this line of code. Nothing was changed.

Comment: I think those 2 line unnecessary :     tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()

Comment: please, add your last comment to your answer so I can mark it as the correct answer. 
you are a hero man.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
self.tableView.beginUpdates()

self.tableView.insertRows(at: indexPathsToBeInserted, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)

self.tableView.endUpdates()
UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
```